# How to read words with ignoring spaces from a file in C++?

Tags: c++, fstream

In my file every row like this:

"ID: HH-123AB, brand: Mercedes-Benz, 128000 miles, 12 L\n"

ID:, brand: miles, and L is the same in every row.
Who can I scan only the HH-123AB, Mercedes-Benz, 128000 and 12?

Comment: You could `ignore` to the next space, but In this case you might as well read and discard them. `fin >> junk >> id >> junk >> brand >> miles >> junk >> no_clue_what_this_is >> junk;` Where `junk` is some `string` you don't care about.

Comment: _"every rows like this"_  How is every row like that row?  How are they unlike that row?  The better you can describe the format of these rows, the easier it will be to read them.

Comment: In this file in every line there is an ID, brand, miles and consumption, which in this example was "HH-123AB" , "Mercedes-Benz" , 128000 and 12 (two strings and two doubles). Is the only way to ignore "," at the end of the strings which going to be read to use the std::ignore and read char by char?

Comment: First, you should "read line,  using getline", then, use the string read as an input string stream, then read from it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following function to "tokenize" the string

```
vector<std::string> tokens(const std::string& csv, char separatedBy) {
    vector<std::string> tokenized;
    stringstream str(csv);
    while(!(str.fail())) {
        std::string token;
        getline(str, token, separatedBy);
        tokenized.push_back(token);
    }

    // Used std::move for performance only, you
    //   could just return it, but it will be
    //   copied
    return std::move(tokenized);
}
```

This function "tokenizes" a string by splitting it, using a separator character.

Then, on your main function:

```
std::string line;
// Get the whole line
getline(cin, line);
// Get all "comma separated tokens"
vector<std::string> commaSeparated = tokens(line, ',');
```

Then parse every portion of it as you want, for example:

```
// First space separated token in the first comma separated one
cout << tokens(commaSeparated[0], ' ')[1] << "\n";
// Second space separated token in the second comma separated one
// Note: The first space is considered one
cout << tokens(commaSeparated[1], ' ')[2] << "\n";
// First space separated token in the third comma separated one
cout << tokens(commaSeparated[2], ' ')[1] << "\n";
// First space separated token in the fourth comma separated one
cout << tokens(commaSeparated[3], ' ')[1] << "\n";
```